# Video upload fail using ng2-file-upload in Angular7 ASP .Net Core 2.1

Tags: typescript, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

In my project I used ng2-file-upload for upload photos & videos to server.Photo upload part is working properly. But video file size greater than 27MB can't upload.When I call to Uploader.UploadAll method then upload method hide and file upload automatically canceled.In the browser console show an error called

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I want to upload video file at least 100MB.

Here is the html code

```
<div *ngIf="authService.currentUser && authService.currentUser.id == user.id" class="row mt-3">

  <div class="col-md-3">

      <h3>Upload files</h3>

      <div ng2FileDrop
           [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
           (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
           [uploader]="uploader"
           class="card bg-faded p-3 text-center mb-3 my-drop-zone">
           <i class="fa fa-upload fa-3x"></i>
          Drop Videos Here
      </div>

   Single
      <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px" *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length">

      <h3>Upload queue</h3>
      <p>Queue length: {{ uploader?.queue?.length }}</p>

      <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th width="50%">Name</th>
              <th>Size</th>

          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr  *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
              <td><strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong></td>
              <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>

          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>

      <div>
          <div>
              Queue progress:
              <div class="progress mb-4">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
              <span class="fa fa-upload"></span> Upload
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.cancelAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.isUploading">
              <span class="fa fa-ban"></span> Cancel
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
              <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Remove
          </button>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my typescript code

```
initializeUploader() {
    this.uploader = new FileUploader({
      url: this.baseUrl + 'api/users/' + this.authService.decodedToken.nameid + '/videos',
      authToken: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      isHTML5: true,
      allowedFileType: ['video'],
      removeAfterUpload: true,
      autoUpload: false,
      maxFileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024

    });

    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };

    this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      if (response) {
        const res: Video = JSON.parse(response);
        const video = {
          id: res.id,
          url: res.id,
          dateAdded: res.dateAdded,
          description: res.description,
          fileExtension: res.fileExtension,
          thumbs: ''
        };
        this.videos.push(video);
      }
    };
  }
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem,This problem happen if I choose file size greater than 27MB.

thanks

Comment: If someone can, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by changing program.cs file.This is not a problem with ng2-file-upload library.In my case my project is running on kestrel server,So I added this line to program.cs file.

```
 .UseKestrel(options =>
          {
             options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200;
          })
```

here is the pull code place

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
                     {
                         builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
                         builder.AddFilter("ApiServer", LogLevel.Debug);
                         builder.AddSerilog();
                     })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel(options =>
              {
                 options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200;
              })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Then after I added [RequestFormLimits] and [RequestSizeLimit] attributes on top of the upload() method in my controller class

```
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Guid userId,
        [FromForm]VideoForCreationDto videoForCreationDto)
    {}
```

If you are using iis server,then add this code to web.config file.Actually I got this code from another place.So I'm not sure for this one.I thought this is helpfull for some one,that's why adding this code.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```